# Jquery move elements by sorting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with the sorting and arrangement of elements. Firstly, I need to sort elements by some value (for example price, date, name) and then apply the layout of elements on the page according to this value. I found a lot of plugins and the sorting functions but they just change the value in the elements under the arrangement. I dont know how sort elements and then change position of them according the sorting value.

For example i have html structure:

```
<div id="page-wrap>
    <ul>
    <li class="first">
    <p class="price">2500</p>
    </li>
    <li class="second">
    <p class="price">4300</p>
    </li>
    <li class="third">
    <p class="price">1800</p>
    </li>
    <li class="fourth">
    <p class="price">3871</p>
    </li>
    </ul> </div>
```

And result should be(for example sort and move elements by lowest price):

```
<div id="page-wrap">

    <ul>
    <li class="third">
    <p class="price">1800</p>
    </li>
    <li class="fisrt">
    <p class="price">2500</p>
    </li>
    <li class="fourth">
    <p class="price">3871</p>
    </li>
    <li class="second">
    <p class="price">4300</p>
    </li>

    </ul></div>
```

As you can see I want to change whole arrangement of elements by it lowest price, not only the value.

If some Guru know how to do this by jquery or javascript I will be very grateful to him.

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 5):

Without making use of plugins, this should work:

```
function comparePrice(a, b) {
  return (parseInt($(a).find(".price").text(), 10) - parseInt($(b).find(".price").text(), 10));
}

$("li").sort(comparePrice).appendTo("#page-wrap ul");
```

Comment: No need for each. `$("li").sort(comparePrice).appendTo("#page-wrap ul")` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this insertion sort method does change your object positions:

http://www.tomgreenaway.com/2009/01/jquery-list-insertion-sort-plugin/

I think you'll have to adjust it to your own needs though, because you want to sort on the price inside the `p`.